# htaccess rewrite only works the first time

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The problem i'm facing with is:
When i hit a submit button from a Form the action is set to a relative path.
the first time i hit the button the rewrite htaccess gives me a perfectly URL
but when i hit it again it brings me the wrong URL.

example:

First this is my htacces file:

```
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /public

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and this it what i want:

**www.example.dev/public/controller/method/params**
The rewrite gives me a perfect URL so that i can extract:
1- the controller
2- the right methode with a couple params.
**i got this working.**

but when i have the following code:

```
    <form class="fomulier" action="controller_example/method_example"  method="post">
      <div class="search">
         <label for="search" class="title">Search:</label><br/>
         <input type="text" id="search" name="search" value=""/>

         <input type="submit" value="Search">
     </div>
   </form>
```

**www.example.dev/public/controller_example** brings me to the form.
Then when i hit the (submit)button it brings me to:
www.example.dev/public/controller_example/**method_example**
**perfect!!!** exactly what i want.
Now i'm back at the form and a methode (**method_example**) is past.

But when i hit the submit button again now it fails.
The URL that i now got is:
www.example.dev/public/controller_example/**controller_example/method_example**
and hit it again:
www.example.dev/public/controller_example/controller_example/**controller_example/method_example**

and so on

So i.m stuck at this can't get it right, anyone??

**ps:** my appologies for my bad Englisch i'm Dutch.

Comment: It could be that by hitting 'back' button, browser's address bar is either showing `www.example.dev/public/controller_example/` or `/controller_example` is being prepended to form action URL. Consider using static absolute path for ensuring.

Comment: I a'm not using the back button just simply hit the submit button. The action of the form brings to first URL only whit a method so the controller->methode now the model is initiated to proces the POST[data] and give back. The controller->methode now brings me back to the form. Only with results.

Comment: The absolute path gives me the same problem only now with the complete URL

Comment: Is your form action URL generated dynamically?

Comment: I think so:   i'm using the URL to routing my app. by Get url in a array. now the array[0] = the controller to load an array[1] is the method to load.

Comment: what i'm trying to get is: form action brings me to a Url then htaccess rewrite it in propper Url so my routing.php can pick it up. the strange thing is it works only the first time when i hit the button not the second.

Comment: If your form or action part is generated dynamically (using PHP methods) then post whole intact form block.

Comment: Hmm now i see no the form action isn't generated by a method just As the example code above. Action="controller_ex/method_ex".  Now the rewrite is from rebase www.rsmk.de /public/.      And there comes the action ( controller_ex/method_ex).  So first hit does the trick but the second sets i think the rebase not to /public but to /public/controller_ex.   And there comes the action Again so the url now is /public/controller_ex/controller_ex/method_ex and this is where my routing fails because array[0] = controller ( controller_ex). Array[1] = method ( controller_ex) iT should be ( method_ex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved:**
Sometimes it is easier than you think!!!

The reason that the above problem i discribed doesn't work is:
Simply my first URL to show the From listens to,
**www.rsmk.dev/public/controller_example**   butinfact it is:
www.rsmk.dev/public/controller_example/**index.php**

Now when i hit the submit button the Form action="controller_example/method_example" gives me the following URL:
www.rsmk.dev/public/Controller_example/**method_example**
well that is exactley what i want so good so far.
(it brings me to the same page because my routing.php only takes a array of
www.rsmk.dev/public/**Controller_example/method_example** and my method gives me the view page).
so when i hit it again the form action="controller_example/method_example" now gives me the following url:
www.rsmk.dev/public/controller_example/**Controller_example/method_example**
**Wrong!!!**
and hit it again gives me the folowing:
www.rsmk.dev/public/controller_example/controller_example/**Controller_example/method_example**
and so on!!!! because my method brings me to the right view only a differnt URL each time (it increases whit **controller_example** after each hit)
so actualy a **relative path will never work!!!**

I tried a absolute path and it gives the same results each time i hit submit.
???????
so that was the reason i was thinking it must be the **htaccess** file.
after manny atempts and couple hours of searching and asking here.
I finally see the problem.
My absolute path isn't absolute when i **forgot the http://**
**shame shame shame**

manny thanks to revo for helping me out it seems your first answer was the right one